# Tree diagram for PSG

Tags: syntax

In the sentence:

> .... to lend me his car in need.

what will be the tree diagram for this part. I am confused for the part "in need"?
will it be part of NP(his car) or part of VP(lend)?

Comment: It is a prepositional phrase that modifies lend. It specifies the circumstances in which he would lend you the car.... when you need it.

Comment: So "in need" is a preposition phrase but it will come under VP right? "in need" will be one single or should it be split into different?